# How to downgrade wpasupplicant?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, apt, repository, wpa-supplicant

So, after 4 months of research, trying everything possible and impossible, looks like I finally found a solution to solve all my wifi problems on Ubuntu:
https://www.upv.es/contenidos/INFOACCESO/infoweb/infoacceso/dat/955112normali.html
And it doesn't work. First it was "blabla NO_PUBKEY", I fixed it with

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 7FCC7D46ACCC4CF8
```

Now it is

```
E: The repository 'http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid Release' does not have a Release file.
```

How can I force the system to use this repository anyway? I've searched the internet but didn't find anything helpful for me.

Comment: *How can I force this *** to use this repository anyway? You can't obviously because that repository no longer exists -> "vivid"=Ubuntu 15.04 (that is **2015**). Better delete this crappty question and ask about the actual problem you're having, NOT about what you think is a solution and clearly ISN'T.

Comment: It exists http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/

I have dualboot Windows 7 and Ubuntu and RTL 8812AE card. Wifi always works on Windows, on Ubuntu I get "authentication with ac:f8:cc:86:37:37 timed out".

I have wasted ~100 hours and tried dozens of different solutions which I found all over the net. Questions here usually get deleted because censoring bad experiences is just how most online communities work.

So, my research led to a temporary solution: I restart the rooter every morning and use guest wifi instead of normal wifi, then it somehow connects.

Comment: Today I found out that wpasupplicant got broken at some point. So downgrading it from 2.10 to 2.1 may finally fix everything. But Ubuntu doesn't let me. For my security aha. Even Windows asks me if I want to proceed and proceeds if I agree. Ubuntu just refuses to do use the old repo. There must be a solution to force it.

Comment: You really don't want to mix repos. I suspect its a 'better' option to find just the deb and install it. In addition the source they referenced is from 2016, and you don't know when its from, or if it'll fix all your problems. There's often the chance of breaking things if you're using cargo cult 'solutions'

Comment: I 've tried to install deb, but even when executed with sudo it refuses to overwrite already installed wpasupplicant. Probably such programs can't be installed with dpkg, but only with apt.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily install Ubuntu packages at some particular version, see e.g. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92019/how-to-install-specific-ubuntu-packages-with-exact-version).

However, packages may depend on other packages, so you may have to downgrade a substantial part of your installation (and fiddle with the dependencies until you understand what to downgrade).

I would also recommend to not add random repositories you found somewhere on the internet, instead use the URL of your existing repositories, and add old distributions.

And if this

> There are a problem between WPA2 Enterprise wireless and Network Manager 2.4. It doesn't connect to those networks.

**really** is the problem (which we don't know, because you didn't describe your problem), a simpler alternative might be to just disable Network Manager for your WLAN, and instead configure wpasupplicant directly, as the issue is not with wpasupplicant itself, but in its use by Network Manager (if I read your link correctly).

Also, how do you know that you "finally found a solution to solve all my wifi problems on Ubuntu" if you cannot even try it out? You just found a random issue that may or may not apply to you.

Comment: > You can easily install Ubuntu packages at some particular version, see e.g. here.
No, you can't. Try it yourself: sudo apt-get install wpasupplicant= and now press "Tab", there is only one version available 2.10-6.
> how do you know
Because the following explanation makes sense to me: a small bug was introduced in wpasupplicant somewhere between 2.2 and 2.6 https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046810/cannot-downgrade-wpa-supplicant-to-fix-wi-fi-connection-to-a-corporate-network
It is still there in 2.10 and I doubt it will ever be fixed, so downgrading to 2.1 should help.